Is there a way for me create multiple maps in python's folium?
I have the below script where I read an excel file into a data frame and geocode addresses. I had to split out the dealership addresses because that column in the data frame has duplicates and I struggled to only use unique values. But I would like to take what I currently have and save multiple maps based on whether that row has a different value in the dealership address column. Essentially 1 map for every different dealership address as customer address are assigned to the dealership. Unsure if I need to loop or what, so any thoughts would be appreciated.
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Photon
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
import geopandas as gpd

#Load dataset
data_customer = pd.read_excel ("HMA_Defector_Map_Data_Test.xlsx")
print (data_customer)

data_dealership = pd.read_excel ("HMA_Defector_Map_Data_Test.xlsx")
print (data_dealership)

#concat address into one column
data_customer['Full_Customer_Address'] = (
    data_customer['Customer_Address'] + ' ' +
    data_customer['Customer_City'] + ',' + ' '+
    data_customer['Customer_State'] + ' ' +
    data_customer['Customer_Zip'].astype(str))
print(data_customer)

data_dealership = data_dealership.drop_duplicates(subset=['Dealer_Address'])
print (data_dealership)

#geocoding addresses
locator = Photon(user_agent='abcd', timeout=10)
geocode = RateLimiter(locator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)

data_customer = data_customer.copy()
data_customer['Customer_location'] =       data_customer['Full_Customer_Address'].apply(locator.geocode)
print(data_customer)

data_dealership = data_dealership.copy()
data_dealership['Dealership_location'] = data_dealership['Dealer_Address'].apply(locator.geocode)
print(data_dealership)

#identify any rows that failed geocoding
data_customer['Customer_latitude'] = data_customer['Customer_location'].apply(lambda loc:     loc.latitude if loc else None)
data_customer['Customer_longitude'] = data_customer['Customer_location'].apply(lambda loc: loc.longitude if loc else None)
print(data_customer)

data_dealership['Dealership_latitude'] = data_dealership['Dealership_location'].apply(lambda loc: loc.latitude if loc else None)
data_dealership['Dealership_longitude'] = data_dealership['Dealership_location'].apply(lambda loc: loc.longitude if loc else None)
print(data_dealership)

failed_customer = data_customer[data_customer['Customer_location'].isna()]
print(failed_customer)

failed_dealership = data_dealership[data_dealership['Dealership_location'].isna()]
print(failed_dealership)

#editing column names and only keeping whats necessary
data_customer = data_customer[['Full_Customer_Address', 'Customer_location',     'Customer_latitude', 'Customer_longitude','Dealership_Name', 'Dealer_Address']]

data_dealership = data_dealership[['Dealership_Name', 'Dealer_Address', 'Dealership_location', 'Dealership_latitude', 'Dealership_longitude']]

import folium
#Calculate mean of coordinates for map center
map_center = [data_customer['Customer_latitude'].mean(), data_customer['Customer_longitude'].mean()]

#make map with folium
mymap = folium.Map(location=map_center, zoom_start=10) #adjust as needed

#Add markers from font awesome
for index, row in data_customer.iterrows():
    if row['Customer_latitude'] and row['Customer_longitude']:
        folium.Marker([row['Customer_latitude'], row['Customer_longitude']],     icon=folium.Icon(color="blue", icon="home", prefix='fa')).add_to(mymap)

icon = folium.features.CustomIcon('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Hyundai_Motor_Company_logo.svg', icon_size=(125,125))

for index, row in data_dealership.iterrows():
    if row['Dealership_latitude'] and row['Dealership_longitude']:
        folium.Marker([row['Dealership_latitude'], row['Dealership_longitude']],     icon=icon).add_to(mymap)

import io
from PIL import Image
import selenium

img_data = mymap._to_png(5)
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
img.save('geocoded_map_test.png')
print('map generated successfully')

file_name='Dealership_GeoCoding_CustomerData_Test.xlsx'
data_customer.to_excel(file_name)
file_name='Dealership_GeoCoding_DealershipData_Test.xlsx'
data_dealership.to_excel(file_name)
print('dataframe is written to excel file successfully')

